# MySQL to MySQLi Convert Samples

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

If someone could just show me how to replace / fix it for mysqli I'd appreciate.
Here are two examples, so I can learn from them and go through to fix everything required.

> Sample 1:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/database.php';
mysql_select_db(databasename, mysql_connect(server, user, pass));

$q_settings = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings");

$settings = array();
while ($setting_one = mysql_fetch_array($q_settings)) {
    $settings[$setting_one["name"]] = $setting_one["value"];
}
```

> Sample 2:

```
$one_blog = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]) . "' LIMIT 1"));
```

Thanks for any tips and samples. I've tried some samples from php.net user comments but I failed in some cases. Here's what I did.

```
$db_select = mysqli_connect(server, user, pass, databasename) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($db_select));

$db_query = "SELECT * FROM settings";
$db_result = $db_select->query($db_query) or die("Error in the consult..." . mysqli_error($db_select));

$settings = array();
while ($setting_one = mysqli_fetch_array($db_result)) {
    $settings[$setting_one["name"]] = $setting_one["value"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first sample:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("server", "user", "password", "database");
$q_settings = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM settings");

$settings = array();

while($row = $q_settings->fetch_assoc()){
    $settings[$row["name"]] = $row["value"];
}
```

Comment: Well thanks for this sample. I have edited a few with similar lines of code. Cheers mate!

Answer (score -1):

I tried over and over and I believe that this is correct way for 2nd Example of mine.

```
$one_blog = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id = '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["id"]) . "' LIMIT 1"));
```

Thanks Wayne for your first sample. It really helped.

Comment: Why minus on Wayne's and My answer ?